# PyCharm: send selected text to the STDIN of an external tool?

Tags: pycharm

With my previous IDE, I had lots of small text processing tools to aid in formatting headers, comments etcera. For example, I would select some lines of comment, press a shortcut, have the text processed and replaced by a new version with timestamps and eye candy.

In PyCharm > IDE settings > External tools, I can indeed configure to send selected text to an external tool, but only as command line arguments. I will need it to a) send the text to STDIN and b) replace the selection with the STDOUT of the external tool.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. There's an open feature request for this functionality: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76371